# Laravel backpack custom search logic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Hello I am attempting to sort and search through a column generated with backpack.

Since it's not there by default i need to add it myself, the column i am trying to search is a computational column i create while selecting:

```
 $this->crud->operation('list', function () {
            $this->crud->groupBy('email')
                ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as countedAttempts));
        });

    }

    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'countedAttempts', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Total count',
            'orderable' => true,
            'searchLogic' => function ($query, $column, $searchTerm) {
                $query->orWhere('countedAttempts', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            },
            'orderLogic' => function ($query, $column, $columnDirection) {
                return $query->orderBy('countedAttempts', $columnDirection);
            },
        ]);
```

This worked for orderlogic after adding the additional operation and doing a raw select, but for search logic i still get the error:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countedAttempts' in 'where clause'

What do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a where on aliases, you have to use an Having clause.